# How to exclude parent Unix processes from grepped output from ps

Tags: unix

I have got a file of pids and am using `ps -f` to get information about the pids.

Here is an example..

```
ps -eaf | grep -f myfilename

myuser 14216 14215  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ksh /home/myScript.ksh
myuser 14286 14216  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ksh /home/myScript.ksh
```

where myfilename contains only 14216.

I've got a tiny problem where the output is giving me parent process id's as well as the child. I want to exclude the line for the parent process id.

Does anyone know how I could modify my command to exclude parent process keeping in mind that I could have many process id's in my input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to do with just `grep` but easy to do with `awk`.

Invoke the awk script below from the following command:

```
ps -eaf | awk -f script.awk myfilename -
```

Here's the script:

```
# process the first file on the command line (aka myfilename)
# this is the list of pids
ARGIND == 1 {
    pids[$0] = 1
}

# second and subsequent files ("-"/stdin in the example)
ARGIND > 1 {
    # is column 2 of the ps -eaf output [i.e.] the pid in the list of desired
    # pids? -- if so, print the entire line
    if ($2 in pids)
        printf("%s\n",$0)
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

When using GNU awk (`gawk`), the following may be ignored.  For other [obsolete] versions, insert the following code at the top:

```
# work around old, obsolete versions
ARGIND == 0 {
    defective_awk_flag = 1
}
defective_awk_flag != 0 {
    if (FILENAME != defective_awk_file) {
        defective_awk_file = FILENAME
        ARGIND += 1
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

The above is all fine.  Just for fun, here's an alternate way to do the same thing with `perl`.  One of the advantages is that everything can be contained in the script and no pipeline is necessary.

Invoke the script via:

```
./script.pl myfilename
```

And, here's script.pl.  Note: I don't write *idiomatic* perl.  My style is more akin to what one would expect to see in other languages like C, javascript, etc.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($xfsrc);
    my($pidfile);
    my($buf);

    # NOTE: "chomp" is a perl function that strips newlines

    # get filename with list of pids (e.g. myfilename)
    $pidfile = shift(@argv);

    open($xfsrc,"<$pidfile") ||
        die("master: unable to open '$pidfile' -- $!\n");

    # create an associative array (a 'hash" in perl parlance) of the desired
    # pid numbers
    while ($pid = <$xfsrc>) {
        chomp($pid);
        $pid_desired{$pid} = 1;
    }

    close($xfsrc);

    # run the 'ps' command and capture its output into an array
    @pslist = (`ps -eaf`);

    # process the command output, line-by-line
    foreach $buf (@pslist) {
        chomp($buf);

        # the pid number we want is in the second column
        (undef,$pid) = split(" ",$buf);

        # print the line if the pid is one of the ones we want
        print($buf,"\n")
            if ($pid_desired{$pid});
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. That worked. I put it all on one line. I'm not very good at awk so I'll go away now and have a look into what your little script means and how it works..

Comment: You're welcome.  `pids` is an _associative array_ or _hash_.  `awk` is simple enough.  But, for the longer term, if you wanted to learn a language like it, I'd recommend `perl` or `python` for the long term--much more worth your time.  P.S. I've updated the answer to annotate the script

Comment: Note that this only works with GNU Awk; the `ARGIND` is not a part of POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler BTW, the last fedora version that had `nawk` was fc21.  Time to move on.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:unix], not [tag:linux].  What was in Fedora is immaterial for AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, Mac OS X — which are covered by [tag:unix] (as well as various sub-species of Linux).  Where the question is tagged [tag:linux], there's no problem with using ARGIND.  Where it is not, it is important to document that using ARGIND requires GNU Awk to work (IMO) — especially as there's a portable way of dealing with 'treat first file differently from other files'.  You may continue to espouse ARGIND; when I spot you doing so and the context doesn't demand GNU Awk, I will comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler See my update #1.  If I do another awk example [with ARGIND], I'll be sure to include the text at the bottom. You'll spot me?  Am I now on some kind of watchlist [of yours]? I'm flattered but, awk is but the most minor of all my posts, IIRC, this is #2.  And, note, it was geared specifically to OP.  Worked for him--solved his problem [if it hadn't, he would have commented, and I would have adjusted, but simplest first].  Generalizing for posterity is another matter.  Just to round things out, I added a way to do it in perl.

Comment: You're not on a watch list, but I do frequent [tag:awk] (Mjölnir status) and if I happen to spot a problem, I will comment on it.  I won't go searching for it; I've better things to do.  I regard your 'workaround' as clumsy and anti-Awk-like — but we're probably just going to have to agree to differ on that (the `FNR == NR` technique works sensibly in most of the circumstances I've seen you using ARGIND).  It would be simpler and adequate to say something like "Assuming you have GNU Awk".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98643/discussion-between-craig-estey-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1):

Use this command:

```
ps -eaf | grep -f myfilename | grep -v grep | grep -f myfilename
```

Comment: No, OP is _not_ grepping for the phrase "myfilename".  `-f' means that `myfilename` contains a list of regexes to grep for

Comment: I tried that command and it actually returns the same result as the original command.

Comment: $ps -eaf | grep file.php give 3 results;  
$ps -eaf | grep file.php | grep -v grep gives 2 results without grep